# Unintentional Looping in Python

Tags: python, debugging

I just wrote up the code below, and the issue that I'm having is that it would display all the `print` statements from userInput twice then give me the error `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'input_voltage'`. I'm fairly new to Python, so any guidance would be very appreciated!

userInput.py:

```
def InputParameters():
 import testSetup
 test_setup = testSetup.TestCombos
 print("Please input test parameters. Separate multiple test parameters with a comma:\n")
 complete_power_cycle = raw_input("Please select:\n  1. Complete power cycle including both test PC and SSD\n  2. Partial power cycle only including SSD\n")
 cycles = raw_input("Number of cycles: ")                                                                   
 rise_time = raw_input("Rise time: ")
 fall_time = raw_input("Fall time: ")
 overshoot_limit = raw_input("Overshoot voltage: ")
 overshoot_time = raw_input("Overshoot time: ")
 input_voltage = raw_input("Input voltage: ")
 ssd_off_Time = raw_input("Off time between SSD power cycles: ")
 pc_off_time = raw_input("Off time between PC power cycles (if partial power cycle selected, enter none): ")
 temperature = raw_input("Temperature: ")
 test_stop = raw_input("Stop test upon failure? Y/N\n")
 test_setup()
```

testSetup.py:

```
def TestCombos():
 import userInput                                                       
 param = userInput.InputParameters
 output = open('testParamFile.txt', 'w')

 #form combinations from test parameters

 for a in param.input_voltage:
    for b in param.overshoot_limit:
        for c in param.overshoot_time:
            for d in param.rise_time:
                for e in param.fall_time:
                    for f in param.temperature:
                        for g in param.ssd_off_time:
                            for h in param.cycles:
                                for i in param.pc_off_time:
                                    if param.complete_power_cycle == '1':
                                        param_list = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,i,h]
                                        print(param_list)
                                        #output.write(param_list)
                                    elif param.complete_power_cycle == '2':
                                        param_list = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
                                        print(param_list)
                                        #output.write(param_list)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? This code has severe design issues and I don't think it's going to do what you want it to. Can you add an example of what you would like the output to be?

Comment: `param = userInput.InputParameters()` ? Notice the __()__ at the end.

Comment: That's not going to fix it either since nothing is returned from that function.

Comment: So `InputParameters` calls `test_setup`, which is a reference to `TestCombos`. And once you add the parentheses, `TestCombos` will call `InputParameters`. Two functions calling one another unconditionally - this is an unusual way to structure a program.

Comment: @IanAuld With this chunk of code what I'm trying to do is take in user input and create combinations from these inputs to be used later as test parameters in the bigger picture. The output would be several lists of integers printed to the cmd for the time being.

Comment: @CristiFati i just want to call upon the variables from within the InputParameters function. is the parentheses neccessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some severe design issues here but what you are trying to do can be accomplished be simplifying your code. Instead of trying to get every combination of parameters all at once you should get one complete set at a time and add them to a list so you will have a list of lists of parameters to work with.

**userInput.py**

```
import testSetup  # imports go on top of a file


def get_param_set():
    """
    Returns a list of parameters to be used for testing
    """
    input_messages = [
        "Please select:\n  1. Complete power cycle including both test PC and SSD\n  2. Partial power cycle only including SSD\n",
        "Number of cycles: ",
        "Rise time: ",
        "Fall time: ",
        "Overshoot voltage: ",
        "Overshoot time: ",
        "Input voltage: ",
        "Off time between SSD power cycles: ",
        "Off time between PC power cycles (if partial power cycle selected, enter none): ",
        "Temperature: ",
        "Stop test upon failure? Y/N\n"
    ]
    return [raw_input(message) for message in input_messages]
```

Alternatively you can use a dictionary which will make keeping track of your parameters much easier:

```
def get_param_set():
        """
        Returns a list of parameters to be used for testing
        """
        input_messages = {
            'complete_power_cycle': "Please select:\n  1. Complete power cycle including both test PC and SSD\n  2. Partial power cycle only including SSD\n",
            'cycles': "Number of cycles: ",
            'rise_time': "Rise time: ",
            'fall_time': "Fall time: ",
            'overshoot_limit': "Overshoot voltage: ",
            'overshoot_time': "Overshoot time: ",
            'input_voltage': "Input voltage: ",
            'ssd_off_Time': "Off time between SSD power cycles: ",
            'pc_off_time': "Off time between PC power cycles (if partial power cycle selected, enter none): ",
            'temperature': "Temperature: ",
            'test_stop': "Stop test upon failure? Y/N\n"
        }
        return {key: raw_input(value) for key, value in input_messages.items()}  # you may want to use int(raw_input()) since it looks like most of these will be numbers and 4 != '4'
```

You will now have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'cycles' '4', 'rise_time': '42', ...}
```

You can access the values just by knowing the parameter name instead of it's index which can get messy:

```
>>> param_dict = get_param_set()
>>> param_dict.get('cycles', '0')  # this will give you the value at the key 'cycles' if it's in the dictionary or '0' if it's not.
>>> param_dict['cycles']  # this will also give you the value at the key cycles but it will raise an exception if that key hasn't been set.
```

**testSetup.py**

```
import userInput


def test_combos():
    params = userInput.get_params()
    print(params)
    run_your_test_here(*params)
```

If you want to collect multiple sets of parameters:

```
def test_combos(num_of_sets):
    param_sets = [userInput.get_params() for _ in range(num_of_sets)]
    print(params)
    for param_set in param_sets:
        run_your_test_here(*param_set)  # the star unpacks the list into positional arguments
```

Quick example of list unpacking:

```
>>> def foo(a, b, c):
...     print(a)
...     print(b)
...     print(c)
...
>>> lst = [1,2,3]
>>> foo(*lst)
1
2
3
```

Dictionary unpacking:

```
>>> def foo(a, b, c):
...     print(a)
...     print(b)
...     print(c)
...
>>> bar = {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
>>> foo(**bar)
1
2
3
```

Notice that the order of the dictionary doesn't matter (dictionaries are unordered collections) as long as the key in the dictionary maps matches a parameter name it will be used as if you had done `foo(a=1, b=2, c=3)`

So you can pass a list to a function that takes a number of positional arguments. As long as `len(list)` is equal to the number of positional arguments and they are in the same order everything will work as if you passed them in one by one. [Read more here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Variables assigned inside functions aren't available outside the functions scope unless you return them and save them to a different variable. They way you are thinking of using them would be as class attributes. Creating a new class to run your tests is certainly another way you could achieve your goal.

```
class TestCombo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # there are better ways to do this but this is simplest to read
        self.complete_power_cycle = raw_input("...")
        self.cycles = raw_input("Number of cycles: ")                                                                   
        self.rise_time = raw_input("Rise time: ")
        self.fall_time = raw_input("Fall time: ")
        self.overshoot_limit = raw_input("Overshoot voltage: ")
        self.overshoot_time = raw_input("Overshoot time: ")
        self.input_voltage = raw_input("Input voltage: ")
        self.ssd_off_Time = raw_input("... ")
        self.pc_off_time = raw_input("...")
        self.temperature = raw_input("Temperature: ")
        self.test_stop = raw_input("...")

    def run_test_combo(self):
        # access class attributes like so
        foo = bar(self.cycles, self.rise_time, ...)
        print(self.test_stop)
```

To use a class:

```
>>> test_obj = TestCombo()
# your __init__ method will now run and collect all the inputs
>>> test_obj.test_stop
# will return whatever you set test_stop to be
>>> test_obj.run_test_combo()
# will run whatever code you put inside the method run_test_combo()
```

Since it seems like you are running some kind of test you might be able to use the built in [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) module.

Comment: Thanks, man.. I know that I have many gaps in my Python knowledge and I honestly haven't touched on classes yet, so I thank you for the help. The reason why I wrote up the combination function as a bunch of for loops was to output these combinations immediately and write them out to a file for the user to view. From what I understood, you recommended taking in all the parameters then parsing them out and passing them as positional arguments?

Comment: Well once you have them in a list you can print them to the console, write to file/db or go ahead and use them right away. You can also use a dictionary to store them which will make keeping track of them a bit easier. I'll update the answer with a quick example.

Comment: You made me see the reason why I need a class to get this working, as for where I am right now I'm just trying to get the code idea down and working before cleaning it all up. You've done a lot more than I deserve, so thank you!

Comment: No problem :-), you should checkout the tutorial on codecademy.com for Python. It should give you a pretty good base to work from.

Comment: I'm actually reading through Lutz's Learning Python, but I'll look into that too :) if you don't mind, may I ask you this: can I reference a variable in a function in a class in any way outside that function/class? Looking at the code you have up that seems possible. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be misunderstanding how Python functions work. Those variables only exist inside the `InputParameters` function; if you want to access them outside, you can return them and assign them to variables in the `TestCombos`.

I would suggest you read up on Python scoping, particularly about [functions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) and [namespaces](http://bytebaker.com/2008/07/30/python-namespaces).

Comment: I thought that if a variable is declared in another function you would be able to access that variable, even though it is local to that function? Or am I just sorely mistaken..

Comment: yep you are sorely mistaken - lol, scope rules as suggested before are your friend

Comment: @gkusner yep I just looked back at the textbook I'm reading through... I haven't coded in a while so I'm very rusty to say the least, and I'm going off of what I remember from C. Thanks, guys!